# Mixing private and public/protected methods of the same name causes multimethods to be disabled and is forbidden to avoid surprising behaviour

Tags: grails, groovy, groovy-2, grails-2.2

I just upgraded one of my Grails apps to 2.2.0 which is using Groovy 2.0 and I am now getting this compile error:

> Mixing private and public/protected methods of the same name causes
>   multimethods to be disabled and is forbidden to avoid surprising
>   behaviour. Renaming the private methods will solve the problem.

Based on the following code:

```
def getRootDomain(key) { }

private getRootDomain() { }
```

It's an easy fix but I'd really like to understand the why better.  Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because of the way groovy chooses which method to call, and its potential incompatibility with java.

Have you seen this thread  on the mailing list?

http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/mixing-public-private-overloaded-methods-causes-compilation-error-td367147.html

Comment: I had not seen that.  Thanks.

Comment: This link is broken: http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/mixing-public-private-overloaded-methods-causes-compilation-error-td367147.html

Comment: Both links are broken, please post the answer on SO instead of just links!